# Meaning of "Powerless smile"

Tags: meaning

"Powerless" is the opposite of "Powerful", I kind of understand the meaning behind a "powerful smile" however, I cannot grasp the meaning of a "powerless smile".

> "This may be an underhanded way of speaking, but, I do like you. However, that's only as a friend. No matter how hard you try, I will never be able to think of you as a special woman. That will definitely be something painful for you — something that will hurt you." Saying so, a **powerless smile** drifted across his face. "Which is why I cannot answer your feelings."

What does *powerless smile* mean in this context?

Comment: This question kept me thinking for a while. My best guess is that the writer was thinking in Japanese. One more idiomatic way to write this in English is *a weak smile*, but I'm guessing.

Comment: There are two possible meanings:

 _powerless_ - something that causes no effect, no emotion. For instance: _Her smile no longer is powerfull, at the beginning of our relationship her smile used to make me feel happy, now it is just one more smile in the world._ - It means it's a simple and normal smile, comparated to what it used to be.

In this sentence, _powerless_ seems to mean something not special, unanimated, disappointed, which is from the fact that his feelings don't correspond to hers, which makes both of them feel disappointed. So _powerless_ in this sentence means: disappointed

Comment: We're really straying into literary criticism here in that the word **powerless** is being used somewhat figuratively. But a close synonym might be "feeble", that is, "a smile produced with little feeling, not motivated by strong emotion".

Answer (score 2):

None of the comments above have hit the right note, so I'm going to venture in.

> Saying so, a powerless smile drifted across his face.

What is powerless is not the smile itself but the feeling of the person smiling. He feels powerless, unable to "answer [her] feelings." The writer is attempting to bring that feeling out by ascribing the powerlessness to an aspect of the man in question, namely his smile. One could view this as a maladroit use of [the pathetic fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathetic_fallacy), or as a simple misattribution, but it could also be viewed more favorably as an attempt to conjure up, with an image of a wan smile, the man's sense of resignation and acceptance of the state of affairs.

Comment: Yes, that is how I would have understood the sentence as well - the man feels powerless and is conveying that emotion of powerlessness through a weak smile.  An expression can be described in terms of the emotion it conveys - other examples would be a cheerful smile, or a dejected sigh.